# jQuery getting previous input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div class="panel-footer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input id="btn-input" type="text" class="form-control input-sm chat_input" placeholder="Wpisz tutaj swoją wiadomość..." />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="btn-chat">Wyślij</button>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have HTML like above. My question is how to get the input value when I click on #btn-chat. I have been trying of jQuery functions like .prev() and .prevAll() but those didn't work for me.

Comment: Assuming #btn-chat is $(this), you can use $(this).parents(".input-group").find("#btn-input"). But that input has an id, so if it's unique, you can just call $("btn-input") directly. If it's not unique, I'd recommend using a class instead of an id.

Comment: You can use $('#btn-input').val() directly.

Comment: $(this).prev().prev().val()

Comment: @KiranBhagat `prev()` looks only at siblings, not parents.

Comment: $(this).parent().prev().val()

Answer (score 1):

Given that the `input` element has an `id` attribute it should be unique, so you can select it directly without the need to traverse the DOM:

```
$('#btn-chat').click(function() {
    var inputVal = $('#btn-input').val();
    // do something with the value here...
});
```

If, for whatever reason, you still want to use DOM traversal you can use `closest()` to get the nearest common parent to both elements, and then `find()`:

```
$('#btn-chat').click(function() {
    var inputVal = $(this).closest('.input-group').find('input').val();
    // do something with the value here...
});
```

If you have multiple elements in your page with the same `id` attribute then your HTML is invalid and you would need to change it. In that case, use `class` attributes to identify and select the elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#btn-chat").click(function(){
    var input_values = $(this).parent().parent().find("input").val();
    alert(input_values);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As @RoryMcCrossan has pointed out, if you have multiple elements with the same `id` attribute, you would need to use a `class` attribute instead.

```
$(function() {
    $('.btn-chat').on('click', function() {
        var val = $(this).closest('.input-group').find('input.btn-input').val();
                  //OR $(this).parent().prev().val();
        console.log( val );
    });
});
```

```js
$(function() {
    $('.btn-chat').on('click', function() {
        var val = $(this).closest('.input-group').find('input.btn-input').val();
        console.log( val );
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-footer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm chat_input btn-input" placeholder="Wpisz tutaj swoją wiadomość..." />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-chat">Wyślij</button>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="panel-footer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm chat_input btn-input" placeholder="Wpisz tutaj swoją wiadomość..." />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-chat">Wyślij</button>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="panel-footer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm chat_input btn-input" placeholder="Wpisz tutaj swoją wiadomość..." />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-chat">Wyślij</button>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great! Feel free to upvote the answer. And if it's what you were looking for feel free to accept it.